# VS Code N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages'

Tags: linux

I'm running POP OS 20.04 & have installed / uninstalled VS code. When I run `sudo apt-get update`, I get:

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not a programming question but rather one of system administration.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

For Ubuntu, edit:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list. Remove any unwanted architectures from between the brackets and it should end up like this:

deb **[arch=amd64]** http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main